# Match IDs and subIDs with looped AJAX and Relate them with Neo4j

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, neo4j

OK title may be not clear, but here is the problem:
I have an array where the IDs of some `main-equipment` data is stored. Each equipment entity has some `child-equipment` with their subIDs.
I make an AJAX call to server to retrieve subIDs of each `child-equipment` by looping the IDs of `main-equipment`. Later I want to map the individual `main-equipment` ID with its `child-equipment` IDs and assign a relationship between them with Neo4j graph database. Following what I have came up:

```
for (var j in mainIDs) {
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "https://someserver.com/api/v1/equipment/"+mainIDs[j]+"/childequipments",
     dataType: "json",
     cache: false
       }).done(function (result) {
           // get ID number of child equipments
           var results = result.content;
           for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
                accepts: {json: "application/json"},
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({"statements": [{"statement": "START n=node(*), m=node(*) WHERE has (n.id) and has(m.id) and n.id ='"+mainIDs[j]+"' and m.id='"+results[i].id+"' MERGE (m)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(n)"}]}),
                success: function(result) {
                  console.log('successful');
           }
```

What I am in this query to reach sth similar like following logic:

```
Equipment 11 has child-equipment 20
Equipment 11 has child-equipment 21
Equipment 11 has child-equipment 22
Equipment 13 has child-equipment 40
Equipment 13 has child-equipment 41
```

But I get only one `main-equipment` ID (usually first) with all `child-equipment` ID instead of each of the `main-equipment`ID. How can I reach the above result? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You is using forEach when you do `for (var j in mainIDs) {`. In this block:

```
+mainIDs[j]+
```

or you can only pass j, like `+j+`, or you can alter the for method:

```
for ( var j=0 ; j <= mainIDs ; j++) {
```

and then you will be able to `+mainIDs[j]+`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, asynchronous, loop closure,etc. but still have the problem..

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Hey. It was a typo from other variables caused the problem. But your suggested helped for another issue. Thanks, accepted.